# Python - replace a word multiple times

Tags: python

**Question:**
I have a case where I need to replace the words in a sentence with a `dc` every time the words in the sentence change. The sentence is:

`Sweet Bad No No Long Yes Bike No Yes`

Over the next few times the sentence will keep changing to:

`Sweet Bad No No Long Yes Bike Yes No`

`Sweet Bad No No Short Yes Car Yes No`

So, the output should look like:

`Sweet Bad No No dc Yes dc dc dc`

I want to replace the first instance of a change, from the first sentence to the next, with a `dc`. I wrote a piece of code but it does not seem right. Where am I going wrong?

```
 dont_care = "dc"
 hyp_curr = []
 hyp_next = []

 def create_hypothesis(stVal):
      splitVal = stVal.split()
      global hyp_curr
      global hyp_next

      if not hyp_curr: 
           hyp_curr = (' '.join(w for w in splitVal if w not in hyp_curr))
           return hyp_curr
      else: 
           hyp_next = splitVal
           print hyp_curr
           print hyp_next

           for wordc in hyp_curr.split():
                for wordn in hyp_next:
                     if hash(wordc) != hash(wordn):
                          hyp_curr = hyp_curr.replace(wordn,dont_care)
                          return hyp_curr
```

Comment: FWIW, it's confusing that you initialise hyp_curr as a list, but use it as a string.  You also don't seem to need hyp_next to be global at all.   You also don't need hyp_curr to be global - you might be better advised to pass it in as the second argument each time.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Yup, I was just going to do that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> s = "Sweet Bad No No Long Yes Bike No Yes"
>>> s1 = "Sweet Bad No No Long Yes Bike Yes No"
>>> map(lambda x: x[0]==x[1] and x[0] or 'dc', zip(s.split(), s1.split()))
['Sweet', 'Bad', 'No', 'No', 'Long', 'Yes', 'Bike', 'dc', 'dc']
>>> ' '.join(_)
'Sweet Bad No No Long Yes Bike dc dc'
```

or:

```
>>> [x[0]==x[1] and x[0] or 'dc' for x in zip(s.split(), s1.split())]
['Sweet', 'Bad', 'No', 'No', 'Long', 'Yes', 'Bike', 'dc', 'dc']
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I didn't think of using zip before!

Comment: If there are more than one lines like in the program mentioned, you will probably `append` all lines in a list say `lAll`. Then you can zip all elements in the list using `zip(  map(lambda m: m.split(), lAll) )`. Finally checking if all elements of a list are the same can be done using `lambda x: x[1:] == x[:-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this?

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import pprint

def rep_dc(list_):
    result = []
    for sublist1, sublist2 in zip(list_[:-1], list_[1:]):
        assert len(sublist1) == len(sublist2)
    for tuple_ in zip(*list_):
        set_ = set(tuple_)
        if len(set_) > 1:
            result.append('dc')
        else:
            result.append(tuple_[0])
    return result

def main():
    list1 = 'Sweet Bad No No Long Yes Bike No Yes'.split()
    list2 = 'Sweet Bad No No Long Yes Bike Yes No'.split()
    list3 = 'Sweet Bad No No Short Yes Car Yes No'.split()

    master_list = [ list1, list2, list3 ]
    pprint.pprint(master_list)
    result = rep_dc(master_list)
    print(result)
    result_string = ' '.join(result)
    print(result_string)

main()
```